# Quais são as opções ao Rest?

Tags: web-service, api, rest

Atuamente a arquitetura Rest se tornou um padrão para a construção de API's e Webservices. Mas e além do Rest? O que mais existe voltado à construção de API's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedro, uma API não necessariamente precisa ser Web ou seguir algum padrão de normatização que seja largamente aceito pela comunidade, tais como SOAP ou REST.

Por exemplo, caso você seja um programador .NET, você pode criar um serviço que recebe ou envia arquivos de texto com possição fixa através de uma porta TCP, você terá uma interface de comunicação entre o serviço e qual quer aplicação que o consuma.

Porém, se estivemos falando de WebServices, uma API REST será a forma mais amigavel de disponibilizar o seu serviço.

Caso o seu serviço seja consumido por aplicações das mais diversas origens, o padrão SOAP vai lhe oferecer mais ferramentas para validar o formato do request, 
formas de autenticação, segurança utilizada na camada de transporte, ordem de chamada dos métodos os serviço, utilizar uma transação (Banco de Dados) do cliente dentro do seu serviço, além das outras possibilidades.